# css media-query min-width return a wrong value

Tags: media-queries

I have a droid eris which has a HVGA screen (320x480). But the following jquery command `$.mobile.media("screen and (min-width: 800px)")` returns true. Can any one tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing the syntax for [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) in a stylesheet, and in a `<link>` to a stylesheet. What you're got so far isn't syntactically valid in either context.

In a stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px)
```

In a link to a stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" media="screen and (min-width:800px)"/>
```

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention I used a jquery command: `$.mobile.media("screen and (min-width: 800px)")`